# Is it possible to query the photos uploaded by "Photo Sync" feature from iOS/Android Facebook app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

I am developing a feature to allow user to pick one of his photos from Facebook to do something accordingly.

In fact, I can query all his albums and photos excepting the photos uploaded by "Photo Sync", it is a new feature on iOS/Android Facebook app.

I am wondering if it is possible to query them via graph api for further usage? Any special permission is required?